# Catching UIGestureRecognizer only on the parent view

Tags: iphone, view, overriding, uigesturerecognizer, subview

I Have two view controllers that can hold the same component as a subView.

The component implements handling UIDragGestureRecognizer.

Controller A also handles drag gestures and should **override** the default drag behavior of the component.

So the problem is that if the component is a subView of controller B than i want the component to catch drag events, but if it's a subView of controller A than i don't want it to catch drag events.

Adding a UIDragGestureRecognizer to controllerA.view causes both the controller and the component to receive the drag event which is bad for me.

How can I make sure that the component will not receive drag events if it's a subView of controller A? (I'm adding the UIGestureRecognizer to the component at initialization and at that time i still don't know which controller will hold it).

Answer (score 0):

[component removeGestureRecognizer:component.myGestureRecognizer];

Comment: There are two problems with this solutions, the first is that the gestureRecognizers are set for one of the subViews of component (specifically for a UITableView). The second problem is that the gesture recognizers of component are initialize at load time, and if i'll remove them and then show the component in controller B, than the component will not react to the gesture recognizers.